# GreenButton no longer Accessible?

Tags: c#, .net

[Green Button](http://www.greenbuttondata.org/) is an Energy project from the US government. I am trying to write code to get at their data and to do that they have created a [SandBox](http://energyos.github.io/OpenESPI-GreenButton-API-Documentation/API/). Just recently I was getting data and everything was going great till two days ago when all of a sudden I no longer got data from Greenbutton, completely out of the blue! In the Sandbox, I used the datacustodian_access_token in the Access Token Box:Bearer 2a85f4bd-30db-4b7d-8f41-b046b0566cb3 . I then launched GET /espi/1_1/resource/MeterReading. which used to work giving me response code 200 and atomic xml. Now it gives me response code 403 Forbidden and I get back:

```
<oauth>
  <error_description>No Authorization Found</error_description>
  <error>access_denied</error>
</oauth>
```

I have some c# code which I was using to get data and it too no longer gets data but instead gets an error. The Code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GreenButton
{
    public partial class Test2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string authToken = "2a85f4bd-30db-4b7d-8f41-b046b0566cb3"; //Currently the Access Token due to sandbox restrictions.
            const string apiBaseUri = "https://services.greenbuttondata.org:443"; //Who we are Calling Web API
            const string apiGetPeoplePath = "/DataCustodian/espi/1_1/resource/MeterReading"; //What we want from Them
            var response = GetRequest(authToken, apiBaseUri, apiGetPeoplePath).Result;//Captures there reason
            //responseString().results;
            XMLLabel.Text = response;
        }

        static async Task<string> GetRequest(string token, string apiBaseUri, string requestPath)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //setup client
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/atom+xml"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 2a85f4bd-30db-4b7d-8f41-b046b0566cb3");

                //make request
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestPath).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var Conn = response;
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var XML = responseString;
                //Label l2 = new Label();
                //l2.Text = XML;
                return responseString;     
            }

        }
        //public void responseString(string XML)
        //{
        //    Label l2 = new Label();
        //    l2.Text = XML;
        //}
    }

}
```

I also tried this on another computer on a different network and still got the same issue. What changed in the last two days? Is this on GreenButtons end? How do I find out when they are down, or is it me?

Comment: You should hide your authToken from your post. And the error you got is 403 which means everything is fine except that you are not allowed to get the data. So check in your greenbutton account if the token is still valid for the data you are getting

Comment: Hey, The token and the information used is open to everyone as it is part of the Sandbox API so none of it is sensitive. There in lies the problem though, this same information was getting a response code 200 a day ago. Now I am getting 403 but I cant explain why. I have been playing with this code for a week or so now on the side, so its strange that itjust stopped working when its been good for so long. the page shows the access code is a static element and has not changed in years

Comment: Ok I just checked on their developers api page using their own API call generator and I got 403 code to. So this is coming from their side, they probably changed something you should contact them, nothing is wrong with your code mate

Comment: Thanks! I have contacted them but I have not received a reply in the last two days, hopefully someone answers and when that happens I hope to post it here for future googlers, but until then I guess this is in limbo, Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problem was apparently on their end. Their is no status or other way to be sure it is down, I just emailed Green Button and they responded. The code above works so if your in the same boat please go ahead, Have a good day!